# Preloading (=Caching) a full Website with Ajax – Possible Problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, caching

I'm currently building a portfolio-website for an architect that has a whole lot of images on its pages.
Navigation is done with history.js (=AJAX). In order to save loading time and make the whole thing more "snappy", I wrote a script that crawls the page body for links to other pages and fetches these automatically in the background. So far, it works like a charm.

It basically keeps a queue-Array that holds all the links. A setTimeout()-Function works through them and fetches each page using jQuery $.ajax(). The resulting HTML is stored in a Javascript Object.

**Now, here's my question:**
What are possible problems that might occur when using this on different machines/browsers/operation systems?

I'm thinking about:

- max. javascript object/variable size (The fetched HTML is stored in an javascript object)
- possible performance problems
- max. number of asynchronous requests?
- … anything you can think of?

Thanks a lot in advance,

a hobby programmer

Comment: Besides what I said on my answer: "anything you can think of" is a little too vague, I suggest you edit your question to make it as specific as possible, or it may be closed as "not constructive" (see [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)).

Comment: Problem? Using up bandwidth that the person may never use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might be a good idea to cache the whole website on the client side there are a lot of things that can cause issues:

- Memory
- Unnecessary load on the webserver
- Loading uneeded pages into memory
- Some users have a limit to their internet so loading the entire website is not smart in those cases
- Once the user naviagets away or refreshes the entire "cache" is gone

What I would do is first try to optimize the server side.
Add a bunch of caching mechanisms from the  database to the user, the "Expires" header can really help you.

And if that doesn't help I would then think about caching some pages(which ones are for you to decide) in the offline cache, see ([HTML 5 Offline Features](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline))

That way you are safe even on page reload, keep the memory to a minimum and only load what you need.

**PS**: Don't try to reinvent stuff that the browser already has :P

Comment: Thanks. I guess the possible problems outweigh the advantages, so I'll stick with server side caching. Offline caching seems a bit over the top for me, at least for a simple portfolio.

Comment: Just add caching headers and that would solve many of your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You should queue the async requests, and only launch one at a time.

And since you're storing everything in variables, at some point you (the browser) may consume to much memory, and the whole thing can become very slow. I suggest you limit the size of your cache to a certain number of pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already limiting async requests to 2 at a time. When a request has finished and all images of that request are fully loaded, the next request is triggered.
I'm curious if it is possible to detect the maximum memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to *not to store* fetched content - just fetch it and throw-out. Browser still will cache fetched pages and images in its internal storage, so subsequent loads will be much faster (of course if ajax library does not forcibly disable the cache i.e. by using POST)